# Error in including paths from Ubuntu WSL to VSCode

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, include-path

I am trying to make a new T-Motor Thunder 300A 24s ESC driver. Although I am a rookie in building code, I am trying this on Ubuntu WSL on Windows 10 and having trouble with the includes in various files. I have cloned the Ardupilot repo into a local WSL (Ubuntu), but I am having trouble with the cpp files not being able to open header files which are located in the WSL storage. Currently, I am facing trouble in this part:

[Code where problem is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGkJi.png)

This is my C++ configuration file snapshot:

[Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MOxi.png)

As visible in the screenshot, I have included paths to my Windows C storage, where I have a copy of the Ardupilot repo, which I also have in the WSL storage. So, I am working in VScode on the Ardupilot local repo that’s in the WSL storage, while referencing the libraries (which are present in my C: storage) in the included paths.

Please help me in areas, where I might be inefficient or wrong.

Tried adding the include path for the specified problem, but it did'nt work

Comment: You are making the error that many newbies make. The file c_cpp_properties.json has nothing to do with building your code. You cannot fix compilation errors by editing this file. Assuming your VSCode configuration is typical then the file you need to edit is tasks.json. That is where you add the compiler options to specify your include path.

Comment: Normally you don't (can't) mix-and-match between the Windows world and the WSL world. It is unclear why you ended up with this mix.

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Extract a [mcve] and then include that as text in your question. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].